# Index Maintenance with Ola starting from day x (7 or 9) till the end of month

Tags: ola-hallengren

I want to run the index maintenance from Ola daily, but in my company the firsts business days every month I can't, cause heavy application usage during the night.

So I want to run Ola's script only from the 7 till the end of the month.

How can I to this?

In my script I handle it with a simple if:

```
if 
datepart(dd,getdate()) < 7 return
else begin
```

But how can I do this with Ola's script?

Best regards
Guenter

Comment: is it so easy? add my "if" to "Check core requirements" in ola's skript.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend making changes *directly* to Ola's script for your situation.  Any customization you make to his scripts will be lost when you download a newer version sometime in the future.

Instead, create a SQL Server Agent job to run daily and put your conditional execution logic in the job step

```
if datepart(day,getdate()) > 7 
    EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
```